# Gateway suggestion and network design with Unifi and Sonicwall equipment

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I'm wanting to integrate with a Dream Machine or just a Unifi Gateway in to our network. We have a Gen 2 Unifi Key already so I don't really see the need for the Dream Machine. So question one is.

Should I get the Dream Machine or just the Security Gateway Pro?

Next, our network is setup like this.

- SonicWall (handling routing, firewall, etc...)
- US-16-XG uplinked to Sonicwall
- All lower level switches branching off the US-16-XG

I'm verify impressed with the Sonicwall's firewall capabilities, so I think I'd like to continue to utilize it for those purposed and shift all the routing to the new Unifi device I'm debating purchasing.

With all this said, what would you recommend and is there anything in particular I'm not accounting for improperly designing?

Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You are managing the routing and firewall rules through SonicWall then I will recommend going for Security Gateway Pro. This will help you to manage your network with more security and flexibility. Sonicwall firewall is more secure than the dream machine firewall policies.

Currently, I am using UniFi Security Gateway 4P and Sophos firewall since the past 2 years it works perfectly alright.